# UIElement Reference

Tags: mvvm, mvp, winui-3, c#-7.3

I'm currently rewriting a Joystick Usercontrol from the old typical codebehind usercontrol into a MVPVM WinUI 3 and having a problem referencing a UIElement from the presenter class. Yes I know you aren't supposed to reference the UI from the presenter. Just need help on how to rewrite it. The ControlArea in the Presenter Class is where I'm having trouble with. Can someone tell me how to rewrite these two lines?

The View UI code is:

```xml
<Ellipse
    x:Name="ControlArea" 
    Height="{x:Bind p.ViewModel.OuterDiameter}" 
    Width="{x:Bind p.ViewModel.OuterDiameter}"
    Fill="{x:Bind p.ViewModel.OuterFill}"
    Stroke="{x:Bind p.ViewModel.OuterStroke}"/>
```

The Presenter Class Method is:

```cs
void OnPointerMoved(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs eventArgs)
{
    if (!ViewModel.ControllerPressed) return;

    Double x = eventArgs.GetCurrentPoint(ControlArea).Position.X - ViewModel.ControlRadius;
    Double y = eventArgs.GetCurrentPoint(ControlArea).Position.Y - ViewModel.ControlRadius;

    double disp = Math.Sqrt(x * x + y * y);
    if (disp < ViewModel.ControlRadius)
    {
        ViewModel.JoystickTransform.X = ViewModel.XValue = x;
        ViewModel.JoystickTransform.Y = ViewModel.YValue = y;
    }
    else
    {
        ViewModel.JoystickTransform.X = ViewModel.XValue = ViewModel.ControlRadius * (x / disp);       //A*cos(x)
        ViewModel.JoystickTransform.Y = ViewModel.YValue = ViewModel.ControlRadius * (y / disp);       //A*sin(x)
    }

    ViewModel.OnJoyStickMoved?.Invoke(sender, new EventArgs());
}
```

Comment: It's hard to tell what exactly your problem is. Can you add more info about your question and its background?

Comment: I need to know how to rewrite/move the "ControlArea" reference in the Presenter class into the ViewModel. Since the Presenter is not capable of seeing the View

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of how to make an `Ellipse` follow the mouse.

```xml
<Grid RowDefinitions="Auto,*">
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="0">
        <TextBlock x:Name="PointerX" />
        <TextBlock x:Name="PointerY" />
    </StackPanel>
    <Canvas
        x:Name="Map"
        Grid.Row="1"
        Background="Transparent"
        PointerMoved="Map_PointerMoved">
        <Ellipse
            x:Name="ControlArea"
            Width="10"
            Height="10"
            Fill="SkyBlue" />
    </Canvas>
</Grid>
```

```cs
private void Map_PointerMoved(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var position = e.GetCurrentPoint(this.Map).Position;
    this.PointerX.Text = position.X.ToString();
    this.PointerY.Text = position.Y.ToString();
    Canvas.SetLeft(this.ControlArea, position.X);
    Canvas.SetTop(this.ControlArea, position.Y);
}
```

Make sure to set the `Canvas`'s `Background` to get pointer events.

**UPDATE**

You can also use bindings.

```xml
<Ellipse
    x:Name="ControlArea"
    Canvas.Left="{x:Bind ViewModel.XPosition, Mode=OneWay}"
    Canvas.Top="{x:Bind ViewModel.YPosition, Mode=OneWay}"
    Width="10"
    Height="10"
    Fill="SkyBlue" />
```

Comment: You can't reference this.Map from a Presenter model class. This isn't codebehind models. What you did is what I already have done

Comment: Again "var position = e.GetCurrentPoint(this.Map).Position;"  this.Map is not capable of referencing the View's Canvas x:Name="Map" because the codebehind eventhandler and view have been decoupled into View's and Presenter style coding. 

How would someone point the "this.Map" of  e.GetCurrentPosition ( this.Map).Position;  towards the ViewModel , so the View can bind to it?

Comment: Can you add related of what is in your View, Presenter and ViewModel? Also, what is in your UserControl? The Ellipse only?

Comment: I have already done that. There's nothing in the ViewModel currently that relates to this.

Answer (score 0):

So the only answer I can think of (but I have no idea if this is correct). Is changing the View's Ellipse to:

```
 <Ellipse x:Name="ControlArea" 
             DataContext="{x:Bind p.ViewModel.ControlAreaEllipse}"
             Height="{x:Bind p.ViewModel.OuterDiameter}" 
             Width="{x:Bind p.ViewModel.OuterDiameter}"
             Fill="{x:Bind p.ViewModel.OuterFill}"
             Stroke="{x:Bind p.ViewModel.OuterStroke}"/>
```

Changing the Presenter's method to:

```
    void OnPointerMoved(object sender, PointerRoutedEventArgs eventArgs)
{
    if (!ViewModel.ControllerPressed) return;

    Double x = eventArgs.GetCurrentPoint(ViewModel.ControlAreaEllipse).Position.X - ViewModel.ControlRadius;
    Double y = eventArgs.GetCurrentPoint(ViewModel.ControlAreaEllipse).Position.Y - ViewModel.ControlRadius;

    double disp = Math.Sqrt(x * x + y * y);
    if (disp < ViewModel.ControlRadius)
    {
        ViewModel.JoystickTransform.X = ViewModel.XValue = x;
        ViewModel.JoystickTransform.Y = ViewModel.YValue = y;
    }
    else
    {
        ViewModel.JoystickTransform.X = ViewModel.XValue = ViewModel.ControlRadius * (x / disp);       //A*cos(x)
        ViewModel.JoystickTransform.Y = ViewModel.YValue = ViewModel.ControlRadius * (y / disp);       //A*sin(x)
    }

    ViewModel.OnJoyStickMoved?.Invoke(sender, new EventArgs());
}
```

and adding to the ViewModel encapsulation by adding:

```
public Ellipse ControlAreaEllipse { get; set; }
```

Can someone please tell if me if this is suitable?

Comment: Yeaop. This works. I was right... =P